# What exactly would you be doing / would you have been doing in the new job?

Tags: would

I don´t understand the difference between both sentences. What can I ask my friend about her new job?

Answer (score 1):

The form *what would you have been doing* strongly implies that it will not happen - that you have not got the job, or have no hope of getting the job (it is an *irrealis*, or *counter-factual* form).

With *what would you be doing*, the question of whether you will get the job is left open: you may or may not get it.

(The third form, which you didn't ask about, is *what will you be doing*, which implies that you definitely have the job.)